# Quotient map between products

Tags: general-topology

If I have a quotient map $q : X \rightarrow Z$ and then I form a map $q\times \text{id}_Y : X\times Y \rightarrow Z\times Y$, apparently this is only a quotient map if $Y$ is locally compact and Hausdorff.

Why is this? What goes wrong if $Y$ isn't locally compact or Hausdorff? I would think that the openness of the preimage of an open set under this map only depends on the first coordinate since the second one is just the identity on $Y$.

Comment: Perhaps the best approach is to look at an example in which the product map isn’t a quotient map. [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907972/product-of-two-quotient-maps-confusion) gives such an example, and in my answer I give a pretty detailed proof. In [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/958400/12042) I give another (similar) example with less detail.